# Subtract an amount from a cell until it reaches 0, then move and subtract from the next amount

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, excel-formula, vba

Can you please assist me with the below?  The objective of my excel project is that each   time each time B is found in column A is minus the quantities of A till the quantity is reached.

Only values with A is where the quantities will be subtracted from. 
The next time it finds the next B , it will check any above A’s with remaining quantity and so.

[image]

I attempted the below aswell but was not successful .

```
=IF(A2="B",MAX(SUM($B$2:B2)-OFFSET(A2,0,1),0),"")
```

i was thinking of opting into a vba code.

**For Example:**

With the **first “B”** is the sequence above, the **remaining balance is zero (0)** because 300 -100 leaving zero of the quantity left.  The **remaining 200** will be taken off 250 leaving a balance of **50**.

The Remaining balance on B will always be zero

Comment: So, it seems to me that all "A" are positive and all "B" are negative and the rolling balance is: `=SUMIF($A$2:A2;"A";$B$2:B2)-SUMIF($A$2:A2;"B";$B$2:B2)` (put into cell C2 and then copied down). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ralph With the first “B” is the sequence above, the remaining balance is zero (0) because 300 -100 leaving zero of the quantity left.  The remaining 200 will be taken off 250 leaving a balance of 50.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me. From the first two "A" values you are only subtracting the first "B" value leaving a remainder of 50. But what about the second "B" value. Wouldn't that remainder (again) be consumed by that? Maybe you can write in the above screenshot the expected result and re-post that picture so we know what you want. Following your current logic I would expect the following values: `=MAX(SUMIF($A$2:A2,"A",$B$2:B2)-SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,"B",$B$2:$B$8),0)` (in cell C2 and then copied down).

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for the above that really helped.. i am just trying to make it sequential now. In that each time the formulae meets the condition “B” , I need to know the remaining quantities of A  before they get absorbed, cause a calculation needs to be performed at each of those stages.  Thanks very much for the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the above comments it seems that the answer is to put the following formula into cell C2 and then copy it down to the rest of the C column:

```
=MAX(SUMIF($A$2:A2,"A",$B$2:B2)-SUMIF($A$2:$A$8,"B",$B$2:$B$8),0)
```

In order to calculate the "current" balance of "A" the following formula can be used in a separate column. For example in cell D2:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:A2,"A",$B$2:B2)-SUMIF($A$2:A2,"B",$B$2:B2)
```

(and then copied down again for column D)